# 350z limp mode and low oil

Tags: nissan, cel, throttle, low-oil, 350z

My 350z went into limp mode while I was highway driving, and the check engine light came on. I noticed that the oil was nearly nonexistent, and added oil. The car still wouldn't get out of limp mode.

I read the codes for the engine light (P2119, P2135, p2101), and they came back to the throttle body.

If I replace the throttle body and sensor, will it be fine? Or could there be other damage? It isn't knocking. And the pistons seem fine. All damage that could've been caused from low oil seem alright I think. But what else should I check?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. It would help to know what type of driving you were doing (track, highway, city, etc.), how low the oil was, what the specific CEL code was, what else you've checked, etc.

Comment: Highway driving. The oil was nearly nonexistent. And P2119
P2135 p2101

Comment: The low oil and knocking are related. The throttle issues are not caused by the oil being low. Limp mode is likely caused by the throttle issues. Can you clarify what you mean "*the pistons seem fine*"?

Comment: Also, what year, engine, transmission, and mileage in/on the car? I can assume a few things, but I'd rather not.

Comment: Side note: the VQ35DE is known for oil consumption issues. This cost me an engine on my G35. Always check the oil when you put gas in the car.